# How do source maps work over multiple, consecutive build steps?

Tags: browserify, source-maps

I've tried googling, and there's [some good info](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) about how A-to-B source maps work, but I can't find any explanation of the logistics of **A-to-B-to-C** source maps.

For example, with Browserify it's possible to have input files of different types (like `main.js`, `module-1.coffee`, `module-2.es6`), and use transforms (coffeeify, 6to5ify) to modify data on the way in. The final `bundle.js` contains a huge inline data URI in a source map comment. And it works – if some line in `bundle.js` throws an error, then devtools shows me the original source file and line number, even if it's in a CoffeeScript module.

Can anyone help me understand the logistics of this... Do all the sourcemaps get 'collapsed' into a single source map at the end? Or does the browser devtools have to traverse a tree of source maps until it finds a file that doesn't have a source map comment? Or does it work some other way?

(Maybe this stuff is already well documented and I'm just googling the wrong terms?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're collapsed, as multilevel source maps are not standartized yet. It goes [like this](https://github.com/sokra/source-map/commit/add831db63f209bb6f347be84e0376c0e74983b8#diff-738ad67339b62eefeca31a4d8fa7b73aR94):

```
var gen = SourceMapGenerator.fromSourceMap(new SourceMapConsumer(jsToMinMap));
gen.applySourceMap(new SourceMapConsumer(coffeeToJsMap));
var map = gen.toJSON();
```

Some more info in the [previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21715053/1872046) on Stack Overflow.