# gulp plugin to concatenate multiple source-map files

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, source-maps

My web app requires two compilation steps.

**1st compilation (typescript) step** - javascript files and its individual source map files are generated

**2nd compilation step** - I use SystemJS builder to generate a concatenated bundle.js and its source-map

The source-map generated after the 2nd compilation step, points to the compiled javascript files in the first step.

How do I get it the bundle.js.map to point to the individual typescript files? Is there any gulp plugin which does this or is there any other way?

Just FYI: Stackoverflow already has a similar question but I didn't find any accepted answers in that question: [Combine source maps of two compilation steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709341/combine-source-maps-of-two-compilation-steps)
Also the plugin ([sorcery](https://github.com/rich-harris/sorcery)) specified in one of the answers isn't being actively developed/maintained

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript compile to single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474651/typescript-compile-to-single-file)

Comment: is the information in the possible duplicate enough or are you still having issues? :)