# Babel: pick up existing source maps

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, source-maps

I have js and jsx files which produced by typescript targets to es6. That files contains source maps, produced by typescript too. I want to pass that files to babel. Everything goes fine, except source maps. Babel does not pick up existing source maps and produces the new one. Is there any way to tell it to take existing source maps?

Comment: What does your build pipeline look like?

Comment: Why not just make typescript output ES5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine source maps of two compilation steps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21709341/1048572) (or one of the questions linked there)

Comment: @loganfsmyth I simple invoke cli commands: `tsc --outDir /path/to/target` and then `babel /path/to/target --out-dir /path/to.es5/target`.

Comment: @Bergi because babel supports more features, for example typescript has no supports `async/await` with es5 targets. Also, I want to use `rollup` for tree-shaking, and I need to use it with es6 modules

Comment: @Bergi thank you, I'll check that.