# Remove all typescript decorations from a typescript file

Tags: typescript

Here is my typescript code

```
function foo(){
  console.log('foo')
}
interface Message{
  tx:string
  unixtime:number
}
function bar(x:Message,i:number){
  console.log(x,i)
}
foo()
bar({tx:'hello',unixtime:1000000000},5)
```

What I need it to strip away the typescript annotation and preserve the original line and column information. This is the needed output

```
function foo(){
  console.log('foo')
}




function bar(x,i){
  console.log(x,i)
}
foo()
bar({tx:'hello',unixtime:1000000000},5)
```

Note the whitespace that replaced the typescript annotation

My question is: how do I use the typescript module API to achieve this?

edit: the motivation is to parse the stripped file using the acorn parser, process the resulting ast and generate a new js file with sourcemap to the original file. the whitespace preservation is to make the sourcemap correct

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do this?

Comment: @vr added motivation in the description

Comment: A more sensible solution is probably to generate a source map when you compile from TS to JS, generate another source map when you do your transformation on the JS, and then combine those two source maps together. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21709341/12299000) for example.

Comment: Why, though? Source maps don't require similar line counts. Just compiling the file to js with source maps enabled will work out of the box. But to achieve your desired result, I think you just have to write your own parser? Seems like a questionable goal.